# Find the area bounded by $r^{2} = 9 cos2\Theta $

Tags: calculus, integration

For this question, I first made a graph for the polar curve (lemniscate):[image]

The lower bound is obviously 0 (r = 3 is at $\Theta  = 0$). So, I solved for the theta at the pole by letting r be equal to 0.

$0 = 9cos(2\Theta )$

$0 = cos(2\Theta )$

$\frac{cos^{-1}(0)}{2}=\Theta $

$\frac{\pi }{4} = \Theta $

Finally, I inputted these values into my calculator to find the area. I multiplied it to four because I believe that I am only getting the area of each half of the curve.

$4(\frac{1}{2})\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{4}} (9cos\Theta )d\Theta =9units^{2}$

Are my solution and answer correct?

Comment: what are you using $\cos \theta $ or $\cos 2\theta$?

Comment: Use `$\cos x$` for $\cos x$.

Comment: I am sorry. I edited the title. I am dealing with a lemniscate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Area =4\times\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/4} 9 \cos 2\theta d \theta =9 \sin 2\theta |_{0}^{\pi/4}=9.$$

Yest you are right.

Comment: A typo. The integral is $9\sin2\theta$. But that still gives 9.